# Setting glOrtho and glViewport so top-left of window has coordinates (0,0)

Tags: opengl, camera, matrix, viewport

I haven't used OpenGL for a long time and have trouble setting up a 2D screen where the upper left window coordinates are `(0,0)` and the width and height of the window are the max `x` and max `y` OpenGL coordinates, such that:

```
glBegin(GL_LINES);
glVertex2i(0,0);
glVertex2i(800, 0);
glVertex2i(0,0);
glVertex2i(0, 600);
glEnd();
```

*does* draw one line at the top of the window and one that goes down from the top. I found many examples for `glOrtho(left, right, bottom, top, near, far)`, but none explains what I need here. I hope the question is not too trivial and you can help me.

Comment: i've set glOrtho(0, w, h, 0, 0.0f, -1.0f) but that gives the 0,0 to the middle of the screen, no matter what other variations i try i am not able to get 0,0 to the upper left corner

Comment: The `glOrtho` call looks correct. Perhaps the state is wrong? I suggest to check `glViewport`, the matrix mode and whether or not the projection matrix is set to identity before `glOrtho` is called.